# The problem with localization of bot telegrams on aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, localization, telegram, aiogram

I created a menu in the bot for different languages. Everything works fine, but for support it does not work, more precisely, the translation takes from "ru" and not "en", but at the same time the translation for the rest works fine except for support.
bot.py:

```
@router.callback_query(F.data.startswith("lang_"))
async def on_language_selected(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    language_code = callback.data.split("_")[1]
    set_user_language(callback.from_user.id, language_code)
    logging.debug(f"Language set to {language_code} for user {callback.from_user.id}")

    user_language_code = get_user_language(callback.from_user.id) or "en"
    user_language = localization.get(user_language_code, localization.get("en"))

    menu_kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
        [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=user_language["send_photo"], callback_data="send_photo")],
        [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=user_language["support"], url="https://t.me/support")], #The translation does not work here
        [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=user_language["profile"], callback_data="profile")],
        [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=user_language["send_photo_free"], callback_data="send_photo_free")]
    ])

    await callback.message.answer(user_language["menu"], reply_markup=menu_kb)
```

```
# middlewares.py
from aiogram.types import Message
from localization import localization
from utils import get_user_language
class LanguageMiddleware:
    async def __call__(self, handler, event, data):
        user_id = event.from_user.id
        user_language_code = get_user_language(user_id) or "en"
        data["user_language"] = localization.get(user_language_code, localization.get("en"))
        return await handler(event, data)

    async def on_pre_process_callback_query(self, callback_query, data: dict):
        user_id = callback_query.from_user.id
        user_language_code = get_user_language(user_id)
        if not user_language_code:
            user_language_code = "en"  # Значение по умолчанию
        data["user_language_code"] = user_language_code
        data["user_language"] = localization.get(user_language_code, localization.get("en"))
```

localization.py:

```
localization = {
    "en": {
        "menu": "Welcome! Here's the menu.",
        "send_photo": "Send Photo",
        "profile": "Your personal profile is under development.",
        "support": "Support",
        "send_photo_free": "Send a Free Photo.",
        "used_free_photo": "You have already used your free photo.",
        "requirements_for_free_photo": "You must subscribe to the following channels to use the free plan:",
        "send_your_free_photo": "Now you can send a free photo",
        "no_photo_found": "Please send a photo.",
        "subscription_or_limit_error": "You must subscribe to all the necessary channels or you have already reached the limit of free photos.",
    },
    "ru": {
        "menu": "Вы выбрали язык. Вот меню.",
        "send_photo": "Отправить фото",
        "profile": "Профиль",
        "support": "Поддержка",
        "send_photo_free": "Отправить бесплатное фото",
        "used_free_photo": "Вы уже использовали своё бесплатное фото.",
        "requirements_for_free_photo": "Вы должны подписаться на следующие каналы для использования бесплатного тарифа:",
        "send_your_free_photo": "Теперь вы можете отправить бесплатную фотографию.",
        "no_photo_found": "Пожалуйста, отправьте фотографию.",
        "subscription_or_limit_error": "Вы должны подписаться на все необходимые каналы или уже достигли лимита бесплатных фото.",
    },
}
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I wrote the localization code, it works, but this localization will not be accepted for support.